# How to convert dataframe to numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following `pd.DataFrame` named `df` and I am checking for this condition: `df = df[df['Name'].str.len()>5]`. This condition will remove 4th and 5th row from `df`.

```
 Id                           Name   
  1          lib_mysqludf_sys.html   
  2             lib_mysqludf_sys.c   
  3            lib_mysqludf_sys.so  
  4                           bash   
  5                            lib
```

How can I convert this `pd.DataFrame` to `numpy` and apply that condition to it.

Comment: Answer is in the title itself. `df[df['Name'].str.len()>5].to_numpy()`

Comment: @Ch3steR It's not working, df['Name'] is still the data frame. I think we have to convert the whole df to NumPy.

Comment: @Ch3steR 's comment is correct and gives your expected result. `df['Name']` is a `pd.Series` and is not changed. Why is that relevant?. To avoid confusion you can provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I don't know why but it was giving me an error. maybe I was doing some wrong. the following answer is working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the `to_numpy()` method on your selection. See the following example:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": 
        ["lib_mysqludf_sys.html",
         "lib_mysqludf_sys.c",
         "lib_mysqludf_sys.so",
         "bash",
         "lib"]})

cnd = df["Name"].str.len() > 5
res = df[cnd].to_numpy()
```

`res` is a two-dimensional numpy array:

```
# print(res)
array([['lib_mysqludf_sys.html'],
       ['lib_mysqludf_sys.c'],
       ['lib_mysqludf_sys.so']], dtype=object)
```

If you need only a one-dimensional array, you can get that with `res.flatten()`.